# SilverStripe 3: ModelAdmin with DataObject with $has_many to DataObject gives error

Tags: silverstripe, modeladmin

In SilverStripe 3 I have two related DataObjects, `Order` and `OrderItem`. `Order` has many `OrderItems`. `OrderItem` has one `Order`.

I am managing `Order` with ModelAdmin.

I can create a new `OrderItem` but when it tries to load I get the following error:

> SELECT DISTINCT "OrderItem"."ClassName", "OrderItem"."Created", "OrderItem"."LastEdited", "OrderItem"."ItemQuantity", "OrderItem"."ItemDiscount", "OrderItem"."OrderID", "OrderItem"."ProductID", "OrderItem"."ID", CASE WHEN "OrderItem"."ClassName" IS NOT NULL THEN "OrderItem"."ClassName" ELSE 'OrderItem' END AS "RecordClassName", "Product"."Title"
>   FROM "OrderItem"
>   WHERE ("OrderID" = '9') AND ("OrderItem"."ID" = 11)
>   ORDER BY Product.Title ASC
>   LIMIT 1
>
> Unknown column 'Product.Title' in 'field list'

Here is my code:

```
class Order extends DataObject { 
    public static $db = array(
        'OrderDate'=>'Date',
        'FulfilledDate'=>'Date',
        'OrderStatus'=>'Enum("New, InvoiceRequested, InvoiceSent, Paid, Cancelled")',
        'ShippingStatus'=>'Enum("Unshipped, Shipped")'
    );

    public static $has_one = array(
        'Customer' => 'Customer'
    );  

    public static $has_many = array(
        'OrderItems' => 'OrderItem'
    );
    // ...
}

class OrderItem extends DataObject { 

    public static $db = array(
        'ItemQuantity'=>'Int',
        'ItemDiscount'=>'Decimal'
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array( 
        'Product.Title',
        'ItemQuantity',
        'ItemDiscount'
    );

    public static $has_one = array(
        'Order' => 'Order',
        'Product' => 'Product'
    );
    // ...
}
```

Any thoughts on how can I add a join in ModelAdmin to the `Product` object/table?

### Edit

I have found the problem I had.

```
public static $default_sort = array('Product.Title');
```

Removing that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just so there is one less unanswered question, @MilesParker edited into the question:

> I have found the problem I had.
>
> ```
> public static $default_sort = array('Product.Title');
> ```
>
> Removing that fixed the issue.

This line would have been on the `OrderItem` class as that is what the SQL error shows. The issue could have been caused by the lack of a `dev/build` however it may have also been due to a bug in that specific version of Silverstripe 3.0.